# EXCEL: Passing multiple values from an array into sumif

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

Question: Is it possible to pass multiple values of an array into a sumif function in excel?

Say I have the following data:

```
| Borders | Counts      |
|---------|-------------|
| Y       | 44.99951609 |
| N       | 9515.258317 |
| N       | 997.900111  |
| Y       | 246.9934189 |
| Y       | 36.998679   |
```

I want to write several conditions for Y, N and ALL. I know that I can write the following formula which works:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(X3:X14,D3:D14,{"Y","N"}))
```

However, is it possible to pass both the values of the array: `{"Y","N"}` from a different cell? For example when I try define the array `{"Y","N"}` in cell `A1`, and then reference this in the formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(X3:X14,D3:D14,A1))
```

**The SUMIF only returns the Y value, how can I get this to return both values in the array (Y and N)?**

Comment: Isn't it far more logical to have "Y" and "N" placed in separate cells, e.g. A1 and A2, after which the required formula is straightforward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not simplifying your actual use case then:

```
=SUMIF(X3:X14,IF(A1="ALL","*",A1),D3:D14)
```

should work (you can type "Y", "N" or "ALL")

More extensible to >2 choices (provided you just have single-letter values, but could be modified provided all potential values are the same length):

```
=SUM(SUMIF(X3:X14,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1),D3:D14))
```

using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can type "Y", "N" or "YN"